# How can I perform solr atomic updates without a distributed update processor?

Tags: solr, lucene, solrcloud

I'm running a solr cluster in kubernetes, and my organization manages our own shards rather than letting solr distribute documents automatically. Therefore we've replaced `DistributedUpdateProcessorFactory` with `NoOpDistributingUpdateProcessorFactory` in the `solrconfig.xml`. This is happening in my application code, but I can reproduce the behavior with simple curls from the shell:

```
# send an update to a document in shard 0 that adds a value to each field
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type:application/json" --data "[{'id': 'my_doc_id', 'my_field1': {add: ['foo']}, 'my_field2': {add: ['bar']}]" "http://solr-0.solr-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:8983/solr/my_collection/update?commit=false"

# commit the update to the shard (along with updates to other docs I might have sent)
curl -X GET "http://solr-0.solr-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:8983/solr/my_collection/update?commit=true"
```

Where `my_field1` and `my_field2` are both multivalued string fields (I basically want to store a list of strings that I pull out of some data I'm processing).

The response solr gives is:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":400,
    "QTime":3},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"RunUpdateProcessor has received an AddUpdateCommand containing a document that appears to still contain Atomic document update operations, most likely because DistributedUpdateProcessorFactory was explicitly disabled from this updateRequestProcessorChain",
    "code":400}}
```

So my question is, why are atomic updates prohibited without a distributed update processor, and is there a way to get around this and send atomic updates to individual shards explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that since atomic updates requires reading the document first, changing the fields and then re-indexing the document, the RunUpdateProcessor only receives the already changed document without any of the update/add commands present.

This transformation is the responsibility of `DistributedUpdateProcessorFactory`, since in normal settings it has to retrieve the document from the node that contains it, and apply the update and then submit it to `RunUpdateProcessor`.

You can implement this functionality yourself instead by [using the optimistic concurrency feature](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/updating-parts-of-documents.html#UpdatingPartsofDocuments-OptimisticConcurrency) with `_version_`, or create a custom replacement for `DistributedUpdateProcessorFactory` that resolves an update request by fetching it from the index.

The old wiki says that the `DistributedUpdateProcessor` is a no-op for single core instances, but [that doesn't seem to be the case](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/update/processor/DistributedUpdateProcessor.java) any longer.

But if you're running without a cluster setup, the DistributedUpdateProcessorFactory wouldn't do anything in relation to distribution - i.e. as long as you've configured your Solr instances to be standalone, that should work just fine. This might be an architectural issue + solr configuration instead of an issue with the update processor.